# InvalidOperationException when trying to access Body from Message

Tags: c#, message-queue, msmq

I try to access the messages of the windows message queue:

```
var activeQueue = new MessageQueue("\\myhost\\private$\\just.a.queue", QueueAccessMode.Receive);
foreach(message in _activeQueue.GetAllMessages().ToList()) {
   Console.WriteLine(message.Body);
}
```

I receive an InvalidOperationException when trying to access `message.Body` (And on nearly every other property other than Id - fields).

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: Ein Formatierungsprogramm, das diese Meldung lesen kann, wurde nicht gefunden.
   bei System.Messaging.Message.get_Body()
   bei QueueTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\QueueTest\Program.cs:Zeile 25.
Translated: "cannot find a formatting program that can read this message" or something like that

Your question led me to the right direction. Looks like I have to provide a formatter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Soner Gönül I was able to solve my problem. This is the solution:

```
message.Formatter = new ActiveXMessageFormatter();
var reader = new StreamReader(message.BodyStream);
var msgBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(msgBody)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, there are two possibilities how to use a formatter to decode a message:

```
Queue.Formatter = new MessageFormatter(); // Set formatter on queue
Msg = Queue.Receive();
Body = Msg.Body;
```

or

```
Msg = Queue.Receive();
Msg.Formatter = new MessageFormatter(); // Set formatter on msg
Body = Msg.Body;
```

which can also be combined:

```
Queue.Formatter = new MessageFormatter();
Msg = Queue.Receive();
if(Msg.Label.Contains('Other')) Msg.Formatter = new OtherMessageFormatter();
Body = Msg.Body;
```

but the following will fail:

```
Msg = Queue.Receive();
Queue.Formatter = new MessageFormatter();
```

because when the queue receives a message, the message's formatter is initialized as the queue's current formatter, so it won't work if the queue's formatter is only set after the first message has already been received.